# How to dynamically create radio buttons using an array?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to dynamically create radio buttons using a given array of strings:

```
var myArray = ['oranges','apples','grapes'];
```

I have already created selection boxes via an array and a for loop, but cannot get it working for a radio button.

Also, I will would appreciate if the solution was written using JS Modern Syntax.

Any ideas? Thank you.

edit:

i created the elements with a for loop:
`for(let i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++) {  var label = document.createElement('label');  label.innerHTML = campus[i]; var input = document.createElement('input');  input.type = "checkbox";  input.name = fruit[i];  input.value = i;  document.getElementById('fruit').appendChild(label); document.getElementById('fruit').appendChild(input); }`
When trying to retrieve selected values:
```
function getOption() {

````
    var selects = document.getElementById("fruit");
    var selectOpt = selects.options[selects.selectedIndex].value;
    document.write("You selected: "+ selects);
     }
```
````

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I used the appendchild function. My only problem now is returning the user selected checkboxes and radio buttons i created using an array. Unsure how to do this as previous for loops are not working.

Comment: Please add all attempts to the question by editing it

Comment: it has been edited to show this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var fruits =  ['oranges','apples','grapes'];

// Dinamically create radio buttons for each element in the fruits array
fruits.forEach((value, index)=> {
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.innerHTML = value;
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = "radio";
    input.name = value;
    input.value = index;
    document.body.appendChild(label);
    document.body.appendChild(input);
});
```

Comment: is there a way to do this with a for statement?

Comment: for(let i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.innerHTML = fruits[i];
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = "radio";
    input.name = fruits[i];
    input.value = i;
    document.body.appendChild(label);
    document.body.appendChild(input);
}

Comment: Thank you! i tried this, although it allows for more that one button to be checked.